# How to access the GitLab API?

Tags: gitlab

After reading the documentation on GitLab's API I could only find the following example URL:

```
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/
```

But I'm wondering what the root URL of the API of my projects on GitLab is?
I've tried `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/` with the `Private-Token` header set to a Personal Access Token I've created for myself, but it always returns `401: Unauthorized`.

What is the correct URL and method to connect to GitLab's API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/` is API address of your GitLab instance (if you are using GitLab.com, choose `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/` instead) , and `/api/v4/` is a prefix and should be used for all scenarios!
GitLab API provides so many resources, see: [GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/)

#### Some examples:

You need to get your project's releases ([Projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html)):

```sh
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN`:` ${YOUR_TOKEN}" http://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/releases/
```

You want to create a new Issue ([Issue API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html)):

```sh
curl --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN`:` ${YOUR_TOKEN}" --request POST "http://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/issues?title=${ISSUE_TITLE}&labels=${LABELS}&description=${ISSUE_DESCRIPTION}"
```

Comment: Ok, I don't know what is different from what I've tried but today it decided to work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about access tokens. You have to create a personal access token, not a deploy token.

[How to create access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html)